# Why is BinaryFormatter not supporting Version Tolerance?

Tags: unity-game-engine

According the the .NET docs, Version Tolerance was added to BinaryFormatter in .NET 2.0: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163902.aspx#S10

So in theory, I should be able to remove a field from a Serialized class, and not have things blow up. ie:

```
//Version 1
SaveData {
    public int Num1;
    public int Num2;
}

//Version 2
SaveData {
    public int Num1;
}
```

Even though I removed Num2, the older versions of the class should still deserialize ok, due to Version Tolerance: *"In the case of removing an unused member variable, the binary formatter will simply ignore the additional information found in the stream. "*
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163902.aspx#S10

Instead, Unity is throwing an Error: 
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Field "Num2" not found in class SaveData

Is there a way to get this working in Unity?

[Edit] Here's the code I'm using to Save/Load:

```
//Save
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
FileStream fs = File.Create(path);
bf.Serialize(fs, data);
fs.Close();

//Load
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
SaveData data = (SaveData)bf.Deserialize(fs);
fs.Close();
```

Comment: Show us the code. Are you actually using the BinaryFormatter? Or are you using Unity's serialization?

Comment: I'm using BinaryFormatter, the code has been added to the OP.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That looks suspiciously like my BinaryFormatter code I just wrote.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `BinaryFormatter` **could** be weird (I dont test this case myself), because Unity use some weird version of [Mono](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/mono) instead of MS.NET. So, .NET docs may lie :-< (Most of the the times, they work in same way)

Second, i use [protobuf-net](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net) to do data-things in my Unity project. As so far, it works like a charm.